# Why is the azure app service django deploy keep failing?

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

It's been 1 month and I still can't figure out what's wrong with me or app service in azure.

I used python 2.7 and django 1.11.3, with this requirements.txt

> beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
>   certifi==2017.7.27.1
>   chardet==3.0.4
>   Django==1.11.5
>   idna==2.6
>   olefile==0.44
>   Pillow==4.2.1
>   pytz==2017.2
>   requests==2.18.4
>   urllib3==1.22

When I deploy with Local Git Repository to Azure Web Service(Python2.7, Windows) it doesn't seems to install the requirements.

I tried wheel but it doesn't do anything, and via scm powershell I failed to install any of the requirements, example:

> Python -m pip install django

It gave me no permission error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Azure WebApps, Python is installed default at the path `D:\Python27\` which has no permission for users to do any write operations like command `pip install <packages>` to install Python packages to `libs`, besides under the path `D:\home\`.

So first you need to install a new Python runtime at the path `D:\home` via Kudu site extensions, as the figure below.

[image]

Then, you can see the Python directory under `D:\home` which you have the write operation permission.

[image]

For installing Python packages you want, do the commands as below to install `pip` tool.

```
D:\home> cd Python27
D:\home\Python27> curl -o get-pip.py https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100 1558k  100 1558k    0     0  5069k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 6546k
D:\home\Python27> python get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in d:\home\python27\lib\site-packages
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.30.0
```

The next, you can install these packages via `python -m pip install <package-name>`, such as `python -m pip install django==1.11.5` as below.

```
D:\home\Python27> python -m pip install django==1.11.5
Collecting django==1.11.5
  Downloading Django-1.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
Collecting pytz (from django==1.11.5)
  Downloading pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (484kB)
Installing collected packages: pytz, django
```

As the offical document said, for [`Troubleshooting - Package Installation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-python-configure#troubleshooting---package-installation), as below, like for package `Pillow` need compiler for C code.

> Troubleshooting - Package Installation
>
> Some packages may not install using pip when run on Azure. It may simply be that the package is not available on the Python Package Index. It could be that a compiler is required (a compiler is not available on the machine running the web app in Azure App Service).

You need to download package wheel files from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) via command `curl -o <wheel-file-name> <wheel-file-url>` on Kudu CMD, and install them via command `python -m pip install <wheel-file-name>`.

After installed all packages, you can upload your django webapp to `D:\home\site\wwwroot`, the file structure under this path looks like the offical [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-python-get-started) that includes these directories `app`, `<your-django-project-name>` created by PTVS on VS 2017.

Finally, please configure your `web.config` file to make your app works.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="<your-django-project-name>.wsgi.application"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python27\python.exe|D:\home\Python27\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: hey, now I got "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.", nothing seems error while deploying

Comment: @HariAnugrah Please see the logs at the path `D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log` and update your post about this issue.

Comment: thanks, I solved the problems
The problems is, azure app service use virtualenv by default, so the requirements.txt package is automaticly installed to python in the virtualenv... so I just edit the deploy.cmd to install requirements to python (extension)... thanks a lot