# ImportError at / when deploying application to Azure Cloud

Tags: django, azure

I have a boilerplate application, that I wanted to deploy on Azure. Locally it runs fine, but when I deploy to Azure cloud, I get:

```
ImportError at /

cannot import name 'views' from 'eve' (unknown location)
```

I tried changing the import to my eve app.. but I get same error. Here is my traceback: http://dpaste.com/3Q23GMD

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are two ways to deploy a Django app on Azure App Service.

1. To deploy it on Azure WebApp for Linux, it's simple to follow the offical documents [Create a Python web app in Azure App Service on Linux (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python) and [Configure your Python app for the Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python) to deploy a docker image which includes your app.
2. To deploy it on Azure WebApp (classic for Windows), it seems to be no document introduce it now, and there is not enough information for confirming your issue in your description. So per my experience, I think the issue was caused by deploying incorrectly in this case. I suggest that you can try to follow my answer of an old SO thread [Why is the azure app service django deploy keep failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440844/why-is-the-azure-app-service-django-deploy-keep-failing/46443085#46443085) to check your deployment steps to fix it.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.