# Getting Dependency Issues while deploying Python Flask Web API to Azure Portal

Tags: python, pip, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I am trying to deploy **python flask web api** to **azure portal** but getting issues with dependency installation as the figure below.
[image]

I have already added extension -Python 3.5.4 x64 to my azure web app and also using latest version for all dependencies as you can see in requirements.txt file.

[image]
Can anyone help?

Also I have tried this- installing/upgrading setuptools from Azure Kudu DebugConsole, but that is resulting in access denied issue.

```
Kudu Remote Execution Console
Type 'exit' then hit 'enter' to get a new CMD process.
Type 'cls' to clear the console

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\home>pip install -U setuptools
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\home>python -m pip install -U setuptools
Downloading/unpacking setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/16/da8cb8046149d50940c6110310983abb359bbb8cbc3539e6bef95c29428a/setuptools-40.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=88ee6bcd5decec9bd902252e02e641851d785c6e5e75677d2744a9d13fed0b0a
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 2.1
    Uninstalling setuptools:
Cleaning up...
Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1431, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 598, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1836, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 295, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 535, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\python34\\lib\\site-packages\\__pycache__\\easy_install.cpython-34.pyc'

Storing debug log for failure in D:\home\pip\pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

On Azure WebApps, you have no permission to do any write operation under the path `D:\` except `D:\home`. So when you want to install pip for default python runtime which be in `D:\Python34`, it will cause the error `PermissionError Access is denied`.

The only way is to install a Python site extension via Kudo and configure `web.config` to use it instead of the default one. There is an answer of an existing SO thread [Why is the azure app service django deploy keep failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440844/why-is-the-azure-app-service-django-deploy-keep-failing/46443085#46443085) which introduces the installation that you can refer to to resolve it.

And now, I see you have installed this extension, but the python command you called is still the default one. The solutions are as below.

1. Change the environment variable `path` via the command `set PATH=D:\home\Python34;%PATH%` to cover the default one.
2. Change the current directory in the Kudo DebugConsole and move into the path `D:\home\Python34`, then you can directly call `python` which be the new installed one.

Hope it helps.