# Deploy FastAPI and uvicorn on Azure app service

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, fastapi, uvicorn

I want to deploy a simple FastAPI/uvicorn onto an Azure app service.

Everytime I deploy everything seems to work smoothly, but the moment I type in the URL for my webapp, I get following error message:

[image: "Error" message]

On my local machine, uvicorn works fine. On my webservice i run python 3.7 & fastapi 0.62.0.

Everytime I deploy, I start a document called startup.sh with only one line of code:

`python -m uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's your deployment method?

Comment: After querying Application Logs on portal, after testing one by one, I found that the lack of these modules caused the project to fail to run.

Answer (score 8):

Azure App Service for Linux with its Oryx build runner when identifies Python web apps run them using `Gunicorn`, a WSGI server. So your startup script can have gunicorn command to spin up the FastAPI app with the help of Gunicorn's worker class `uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`.

```sh
gunicorn -w 2 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
```

The `-w` indicates the number of workers you want to spin up with Gunicorn as master.

Alternatively, you can make the number of workers to automatically be calculated using a configuration file provided as an argument to the gunicorn as shown below.

```sh
gunicorn --config gunicorn.py main:app
```

And the *gunicorn.py* can have logic that calculates the number of worker processes and other configuration arguments for gunicorn as shown below.

```py
import multiprocessing
import os

name = "Gunicorn config for FastAPI"

accesslog = "/home/user/fastapi/gunicorn-access.log"
errorlog = "/home/user/fastapi/gunicorn-error.log"

bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"

worker_class = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count () * 2 + 1
```

Also there is a detailed step by step tutorial that demonstrates [How to Deploy FastAPI on Azure App Service in just 30 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLdEI3zUcFg)

Answer (score 4):

After deployed webapp, I add some modules and add start command on portal. It works for me. ([Download sample code](https://github.com/Jason446620/fastapi-uvicon))

**1. Commands like below:**

*You also can add fastapi,uvicorn,uvloop,httptools in requirements.txt,let the program automatically install these modules when it is deployed.*

```
root@3a***a3:/home/site/wwwroot# pip install fastapi
root@3a***a3:/home/site/wwwroot# pip install uvicorn
root@3a***a3:/home/site/wwwroot# pip install uvloop
root@3a***a3:/home/site/wwwroot# pip install httptools
```

**2. Settings-> Configuration->General settings-> Startup Command.**

```
gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
```

[image]

## Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use uvicorn activating build during deployment with configuration SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = 1

See my answer in other thread

[Azure app service cannot find installed modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65911260/azure-app-service-cannot-find-installed-modules/76028708#76028708)

I've extensively tested it