# Application Error while deploying fastapi uvicorn

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, fastapi, azure-devops-rest-api, uvicorn

I had a machine learning fast API/uvicorn app which I am deploying in the azure app service through azure DevOps.

Every time I deploy its deploys without any error but still I am getting this message
[image]

I thought the problem is in not using `uvicorn` and added it but still I am getting the same problem. I tried deploying Heroku and it's working perfectly fine. I have tried installing uvicorn and followed from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66251679/16668992) but nothing seems to work. Please help me I don't know where I am doing wrong

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the `startup command` you're running `gunicorn` instead of `uvicorn`...could that be the problem?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I have installed all the required packages. as I have said I deployed in Heroku its working fine there. But I am facing problem in azure